# Can I connect two tee fittings to under kitchen sink water supply?

Tags: water, kitchens, water-pressure, hot-water, ice-maker

We are buying a house and want to do 2 minor upgrades to whichever home we purchase for sure: we have a countertop ice maker that can be connected to a water supply so you don’t have to manually refill it with water to make ice AND we want an instant hot water dispenser. Can we use two tee fittings to connect both to our kitchen faucet water supply line? The ice maker is the only thing taking in water continually, the instant hot and sink faucet would be either or…so we aren’t too worried about competing for water pressure. The other consideration is that all the homes we are looking for have a dishwasher and garbage disposal…I know some dishwashers have their own water supply line and some don’t, is this another thing I need to be worried about connecting to the same inlet as the ice maker, instant hot, and faucet? How is the best way to go about this?

Comment: The ice maker probably has an internal solenoid valve so would not affect water pressure unless it was refilling its water reservoir. I would put in a tee between your faucet cold water shutoff and the faucet cold water supply line, then add an additional tee to that to supply your two devices.

Comment: Might as well connect the instant-hot to the hot supply so it won't have to work as hard when hot is there, and the ice-maker to the cold supply, even.

Answer (score 2):

There should be very little loss of water pressure and only if all devices were open at the same time.
For ease of connection and the ability to shut off the water to the sink or other device separately, consider a [dual shut-off valve](https://www.sharkbite.com/us/en/brass-push-to-connect/valves/supply-stops/brass-push-dual-shut-off-valve). Then a tee from there.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!